# Changing the image source of a droppable with a draggable image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have a `<div>` containing the three images with the class "droppable". The table has four rows with the image inside the last `<td>` element.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="box_container">
  <img id="empty_box1" class="droppable" src="images/tom.png" />
  <img id="empty_box2" class="droppable" src="images/tom.png" />
  <img id="empty_box3" class="droppable" src="images/tom.png" />
</div>

<td><img id="" class="draggable" src="images/image1.png" /></td>
```

Following is a picture of how the layout looks like below:

[image]

The images in the table are draggable into the empty boxes above the table. The boxes consists of an image of white space and I want the source of that image to change to the image that has been dropped into the empty box.

Below is my code at the current stage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    snap: ".droppable",
    snapMode: "inner"
  });
  $("#tabellen").tablesorter();
  $(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function () {
        console.log(this);
        var new_pic = $('.draggable').attr('src');
        $(this)
            .attr('src', new_pic)
            .attr('width', 150)
            .attr('height', 150)
            .addClass('zoomable');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: so what is the question ?

Comment: The question is how do I get the image in the empty box to change into the image that is being dropped onto it.

Comment: welcome to stackOverflow. It'd greatly help those trying to help you if you provide the boilerplate HTML and CSS required to play with your JS, rather than just an image. As it is, we don't know what `#draggable1`, `#draggable2` etc are, or your HTML structure. Please edit your question and update it with more info. BTW you should really use a common class rather than initializing each draggable one by one with `id`'s unless the initialization options are different.

Comment: I have tried to add some snippets from my HTML and I have made a few adjustments to the jQuery. Hope this is more helpful as I would greatly appreciate any help with my problem.

Comment: @Rinusu Does the answer (Setting the droppables source to `ui.draggable.attr("src")` ) help..?

Comment: Yes, it did indeed. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the [`drop`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) event callback, you can access the dropped draggable element via the `draggable` property of second argument (Commonly named as `ui`).  You can *copy* it's source to droppable as shown below:

```js
$(".draggable").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid"
});
$(".droppable").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).attr("src", ui.draggable.attr("src"));
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.draggable {
  background: hotpink;
  float: left;
}
.droppable {
  float: right;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<img class="draggable" src="http://i49.tinypic.com/28vepvr.jpg" />
<img class="droppable" src="" alt="Drop Here!" />
```